# Is there any C# naming convention for a variable used in a property?

Tags: c#, properties

Let's say, we have a variable, which we want named `Fubar`

Let's say that `Fubar` is a `String`!

That means, we would define Fubar as so:

```
public string Fubar;
```

Now, let's say we want `Fubar` to have a getter and setter (or in other words, become a C# property)!

```
private string Fubar;
public string Fubar_gs
{
    get
    {
        //Some fancy logic
        return Fubar;
    }
    set
    {
        //Some more fancy logic
        Fubar = value;
    }
}
```

Well great! That is all fine and dandy, EXCEPT, what if I wanted the PROPERTY to be named Fubar, not the original variable?

Well obviously, I would just rename both variables. But the problem is, what would be the best name for the original variable?

Is there a naming convention for this situation?

Comment: Note that this works also: `public string Fubar{get;set;}`

Comment: Just rename the private member fubar, mfubar, _fubar, fFubar ,pfubar , pick a standard and stick to it.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Per [Microsoft's naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), the proper way would be:

```
private string fubar;
public string Fubar { get { return fubar; } set { fubar = value; } }
```

However, many people prefer to prefix the private field with an underscore to help minimize the possibility of miscapitalizing and using the field when they meant to use the property, or vice versa.

Thus, it's common to see:

```
private string _fubar;
public string Fubar { get { return _fubar; } set { _fubar = value; } }
```

The approach you take is ultimately up to you. StyleCop will enforce the former by default, whereas ReSharper will enforce the latter.

In C# 6, there is new syntax for declaring default values for properties or making read-only properties, lessening the need for properties with backing fields that don't have any special additional logic in the `get` and `set` methods.  You can simply write:

`public string Fubar { get; set; } = "Default Value";`

or

`public string Fubar { get; } = "Read-only Value";`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You were not the first person to provide the _underscore, however I have to say, yours was the most informative! Selected answer for including the standard AS WELL as the generally accepted

Comment: On [Microsoft naming **GUIDELINES**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is stated that _internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines_ which slightly contradicts this post.

Comment: [Microsoft Capitalization Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx#Anchor_2) also state _DO NOT assume that all programming languages are case sensitive. They are not. Names cannot differ by case alone._ As mentioned in the above comment, there is no guidance provided for private instance fields which really leaves property backing field conventions up to the developer.

Comment: There's actually an easier/cleaner way for read-only fields for C#6, which is `public string Fubar => "Read-only Value";`

Comment: @thudbutt - that rule is ONLY when BOTH names are externally visible (thus could be accessed by a different CLR language). A "private" declaration (`private string fubar;`) can only be seen by the current language compiler (C#), so **CAN** merely differ in case from a public declaration (`public string Fubar ...`).

Comment: Actually his is no longer the case. They don't actually specify for private properties only public properties and private fields. 

But the same reason its better for private fields could be applied to private properties. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Answer (score 10):

prefix the private with an underscore  `_fubar`

as a good guide, you can use the CLR runtimes teams coding style guide which goes beyond the standard naming guideline from Microsoft

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md

Comment: No, please don't use any underscorse.

Comment: I think you mean "use any underscorse[sic], please don't"

Comment: One benefit of underscore prefix, is that inside an instance method, it is immediately obvious whether a reference is to a private field, rather than to a method property.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah, there is no real negative to using underscores, I've been doing C# for over 20 years and it is just a preference ( which some people don't like ).

Comment: It absolutely increases legibility for private fields and properties compared to local vars. 

It has also been advised as correct usage by Microsoft in their own coding conventions. So yeah, absolutely use them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Answer (score 7):

If you name your private variables starting with lower case, you can right click on them and have VS generate your getter/setter code for you;

Refactor->Enacpsulate Field...

It will name the property with Caps.

Comment: This is a great tip with the minor addition that it works for uppercase variables, or variables starting with underscore as well.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but +1 for a great hint.

Answer (score 6):

If there's no logic in the getter/setter, use an auto-property:

```
public string Fubar {get; set;}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Logic will most definitely need to be used :(

Answer (score 5):

Well, the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) document states the following:

> Names of Fields The field-naming guidelines apply to static public and
>   protected fields. Internal and private fields are not covered by
>   guidelines, and public or protected instance fields are not allowed by
>   the member design guidelines.
>
> ✓ DO use PascalCasing in field names.
>
> ✓ DO name fields using a noun, noun phrase, or adjective.
>
> X DO NOT use a prefix for field names.
>
> For example, do not use "g_" or "s_" to indicate static fields.

So, for private fields, there is no official recommendation. However, if you use VS 2017 quick action "Convert to full property" on a property, this happens:

[image: VS 2017 quick action "Convert to full property"]

So it seems like it is safe to assume that prefixing **private** fields with an underscore is somewhat standard.

Comment: To add, it's common to use `s_` prefixes for static fields if it's the only one representing the class -- often seen in Unity. If you have static props everywhere, it looks ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Unluckily there are no common convention, you have to choose what suits most your case, I've seen all the following approaches in different codebases.

**Approach 1**

```
private string _fubar;   //_camelCase
public string Fubar { ... }
```

**Approach 2**

```
private string fubar;    //camelCase
public string Fubar{ ... }
```

**Approach 3**

```
private string _Fubar;    //_PascalCase
public string Fubar{ ... }
```

Also there are frameworks that takes much creativity like using a property and document it as a member variable and thus using member's styling instead of the properties' styling ( yeah Unity! I'm pointing the finger at you and your `MonoBehaviour.transform` 's property/member)

To disambiguate in our code base **we use our homemade rule**:

- Try to use more proper naming, usually a member used inside a public property has a slightly different purpose than its public counterpart, so it is very possible most times to find a different and proper name, and if not possible its purpose is just holding state for the public property, so why not naming it **nameValue**?
- use autoproperties if possible

With our approach most times we avoid the doubt about the underscore "_" while at same time having a much more readable code.

```
private string fubarValue; //different name. Make sense 99% of times
public string Fubar { ... }
```

Comment: Approach 1 is the most standard, I'd say. Some people don't like the `_` underscore, but it truly helps accidental cAsE mismatch.

Comment: @dylanh724 - Another benefit of Approach 1, is that inside an instance method, it is immediately obvious whether a reference is to a private field, rather than to a method property.

Answer (score 2):

The c# way is

```
private string _fubar;
public string Fubar
{
    get
    {
        return _fubar;
    }
    set
    {
        _fubar = value;
    }
}
```

However, if it's just a basic getter/setter with no extra logic, you can just write

```
public string Fubar { get; set; }
```

No need for a backing variable or anything.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about coding standards is that there are so many to choose from:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+coding+standards
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/19/60315.aspx
- http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/11/top-6-coding-standards-guideline.html

Pick a convention that suits you and use it consistently.

The Microsoft convention — pascalCase private fields and CamelCase properties is tidy, but can lead to bugs due to typos. I find the leading underscore convention annoying as it requires two additional key strokes every time you type the name, but you don't get the typos so much (or at least the compiler catches them first).

Answer (score 2):

I thing, one name is better:

```
public string Fubar { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to declare with a default value

```
    private string _fubar = "Default Value";
    public string Fubar
    {
        get { return _fubar; }
        set { _fubar = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a ton of outdated answers (and non-standard ways representing C#6), so this one's for 2020:

```cs
// "fubar" works, too, but "_" prevents CaSe typo mistakes
private string _fubar;
public string Fubar
{
    get => _fubar;
    set => _fubar = value;
}

// Read-only can just use lambda to skip all those shenannigans
public string ReadOnlyFoo => "This is read-only!";
```

Comment: To clarify for future readers: All older answers used `get { return _fubar; }` or similar syntax, if a backing field exists. This answer shows that this can be simplified to `get => _fubar;`. Note that if that is ALL a getter/setter contains, then, as some other answers show, the backing field can be completely omitted: `public string Fubar { get; set; } = "Default value";`.

Comment: ^ Yep! Also, a naming convention update: the cool thing to do these days is to prefix private fields like this `in` instead of `_`. So, `inFubar` instead of `_fubar`. It's all arbitrary, so it's up to you!

Comment: [rant] Ugh, ugh, ugh. IMHO, prefixing with `in` is a really poor idea. First, of all, "in" is a poor choice. Too many other possible meanings. Second, it clutters the beginning of the name with two letters. Not enough benefit. If would honestly be better to NOT do anything at all to indicate private. Seriously. The reason that underscore is acceptable is that it is minimal clutter. Still reads as "fubar", just with an annotation that you can pay attention to if you want. Names should emphasize their CONCEPTS, not be cluttered with other details; the IDE should help you know if its private.

Answer (score 0):

While most developers follow Microsoft's guideline, as game developers, we follow Unity's style as ([one of the script source code here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/9f418c4767c47d0c71f1727eb42a9a9024e9ecc0/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Text.cs)):

```
static protected Material s_DefaultText = null;
protected bool m_DisableFontTextureRebuiltCallback = false;
public TextGenerator cachedTextGenerator { ... }
```