# How should I name backing properties in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public partial class ABC
{
    string _time;

    public string Time {
        get => _time;
        set => SetProperty(ref _time, value);
    }
}
```

My question is am I correct with the naming of _time where I added an underscore.

Also should I be marking that as private?

Comment: Short answer, however you like. FWIW, that looks fine to me, however i personally would make it explicitly private (though in both cases that is my personal design choice).

Comment: The first question is likely opinionated. It's not the default for private fields in VS (if you get it to generate backing fields for you without a .editorconfig configured with _). It is my preferred style, however.

Comment: You can name them whatever you want. I personally follow the naming conventions laid out by Microsoft, more specifically [the ones they actually use](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2588e246e5ca469603d3253225a5dcecda45a1cd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L30). Also, no, you don't need to mark the field as private, as the default access modifier is the most restricted access. But again, even MS themselves mark all their private fields as such and no linter in the world would get upset

Comment: Also, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)'s a handy link to the MS official design guidelines. Not everything is specified and I personally find that it's not very well documented at all. But it does point out some common "mistakes" I see made, like using abbreviations or acronyms

Comment: "Also should I be marking that as private?" - `private` is the default access for members of a type, so that is implicit - it is subjective, but some people prefer to always specify the access so that you know you've considered it. But adding `private` won't change anything to the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_ is common to indicate a private member.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129214/616194. The default rules in the Rider/Resharper IDE work accordingly.

Comment: Correct is subjective. Why is `_name` correct and not `m_name`?

Comment: Correct is related to the fact that _ is common. See default rules in Resharper/Rider etc. It does not mean that other naming conventions are impossible

Comment: Should I have the word Private before _time?

Comment: see answer from "The General" below your question